# invite facebook button gives an error

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I added a button to my website where, if the user clicks it, a windows open. It should be filled with him/her friends in order to be able to invite them to visit that website. Instead of the friends the following error appears:

```
Game Requests are only available to games.
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div id="facebook_invite">
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="FBInvite()">Invite Facebook Friends</a>
<script>
 FB.init({
  appId:'1085268194891544',
  cookie:true,
  status:true,
  xfbml:true
 });
</script>
<script>
 function FBInvite(){
  FB.ui({
   method: 'apprequests',
   message: 'Invite your Facebook Friends'
  },function(response) {
   if (response) {
    alert('Successfully Invited');
   } else {
    alert('Failed To Invite');
   }
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Are your app a game that is played inside Facebook Canvas?

Comment: Then that is the reason.